# How do you select an element that is the child of another element in Appium using wd and javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, appium

I have a React-Native application on Android with multiple Pickers (dropdowns) on a screen. I have an accessibilityLabel assigned to the first picker component called "Pick Description" and I have an accessibilityLabel assigned to the second picker component called "Pick Price". I am able to find the second picker component on the page using `driver.waitForElementByAccessibilityId( "Pick Price" )` but I need to be able to find out what the text value is in the picker, i.e. the value that has been selected. I am using Jest, JavaScript, and wd.

I have opened the app with Appium Desktop and selected the picker and I can see that it has a child component that is an android.widget.TextView with a resource-id of "android:id/text1".

If I use `driver.waitForElementByAccessibilityId( "Pick Price" ).waitForElementById( "android:id/text1" ).text();` it gets the text from the first picker, i.e. "Pick Description". It looks like it is just returning the first element with the ID of "text1" on the page.

How do I go about getting the text value from a React-Native Picker component when I have an accessibilityLabel assigned to the Picker component but no accessibilityLabel assigned to the TextView?

Comment: I was able to select the text using ``driver.waitForElementByXPath( `//android.widget.Spinner[@content-desc=\"${accessId}\"]/android.widget.TextView` ).text()``, where `accessId` is the accessibilityLabel of the Picker. I feel like there is a better way to do this by only searching within an element that has already been selected, so if you have a suggestion, please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered how to do this. The only search methods that are able to search within elements are the `elementBy...` and `elementsBy...` methods. In order to have these methods operate on the previous element returned in the chain, you need to add `'>'` as the first parameter in the method. This tells the method to act on the element instead of globally. So for my example above, you would use

`driver.waitForElementByAccessibilityId("Pick Price").elementById(">", "android:id/text1").text();`

References:

- [wd docs](http://admc.io/wd/)
- [Chained function calls examples](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/examples/promise/chained-el-func-call.js)
- [wd api (search for "element.element")](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider moving to [XPath selector](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and amend your code to look like:

```
driver.waitForElementByAccessibilityId( "Pick Price" ).waitForElementByXPath( ".//[@android:id/text1]" ).text();
```

this way the second web element search scope will be relative to the first element.

References:

- [XPath Syntax -> Selecting Nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)